# How to read a graphviz decision tree?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, graphviz, decision-tree

I have a decision tree graphviz file that I obtained by using ScikitLearn's [export_graphviz](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.export_graphviz.html) function. For sake of simplicity I limited the depth to 3 so I got this output:

```
digraph Tree {
node [shape=box] ;
0 [label="userAcceleration-magnitude-mean <= 0.973\ngini = 0.875\nsamples = 3878\nvalue = [471, 467, 485, 484, 486, 486, 513, 486]\nclass = Walking"] ;
1 [label="userAcceleration-x-IQR <= 0.073\ngini = 0.834\nsamples = 2881\nvalue = [471, 443, 476, 484, 9, 486, 512, 0]\nclass = Walking"] ;
0 -> 1 [labeldistance=2.5, labelangle=45, headlabel="True"] ;
2 [label="rotationRate-z-IQR <= 0.396\ngini = 0.606\nsamples = 1020\nvalue = [466, 80, 43, 2, 0, 429, 0, 0]\nclass = Push-ups"] ;
1 -> 2 ;
3 [label="gini = 0.355\nsamples = 515\nvalue = [5, 74, 28, 2, 0, 406, 0, 0]\nclass = Resting"] ;
2 -> 3 ;
4 [label="gini = 0.164\nsamples = 505\nvalue = [461, 6, 15, 0, 0, 23, 0, 0]\nclass = Push-ups"] ;
2 -> 4 ;
5 [label="rotationRate-magnitude-median <= 0.844\ngini = 0.764\nsamples = 1861\nvalue = [5, 363, 433, 482, 9, 57, 512, 0]\nclass = Walking"] ;
1 -> 5 ;
6 [label="gini = 0.596\nsamples = 974\nvalue = [2, 73, 388, 476, 0, 23, 12, 0]\nclass = Lunges"] ;
5 -> 6 ;
7 [label="gini = 0.571\nsamples = 887\nvalue = [3, 290, 45, 6, 9, 34, 500, 0]\nclass = Walking"] ;
5 -> 7 ;
8 [label="userAcceleration-y-max <= 2.702\ngini = 0.533\nsamples = 997\nvalue = [0, 24, 9, 0, 477, 0, 1, 486]\nclass = Running"] ;
0 -> 8 [labeldistance=2.5, labelangle=-45, headlabel="False"] ;
9 [label="rotationRate-z-IQR <= 2.4\ngini = 0.236\nsamples = 536\nvalue = [0, 22, 6, 0, 466, 0, 1, 41]\nclass = Jump Rope"] ;
8 -> 9 ;
10 [label="gini = 0.553\nsamples = 53\nvalue = [0, 11, 6, 0, 3, 0, 0, 33]\nclass = Running"] ;
9 -> 10 ;
11 [label="gini = 0.08\nsamples = 483\nvalue = [0, 11, 0, 0, 463, 0, 1, 8]\nclass = Jump Rope"] ;
9 -> 11 ;
12 [label="altitude-median <= 5.0\ngini = 0.068\nsamples = 461\nvalue = [0, 2, 3, 0, 11, 0, 0, 445]\nclass = Running"] ;
8 -> 12 ;
13 [label="gini = 0.0\nsamples = 445\nvalue = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 445]\nclass = Running"] ;
12 -> 13 ;
14 [label="gini = 0.477\nsamples = 16\nvalue = [0, 2, 3, 0, 11, 0, 0, 0]\nclass = Jump Rope"] ;
12 -> 14 ;
}
```

Let's concentrate on the first 2 nodes:

```
0 [label="userAcceleration-magnitude-mean <= 0.973\ngini = 0.875\nsamples = 3878\nvalue = [471, 467, 485, 484, 486, 486, 513, 486]\nclass = Walking"] ;
1 [label="userAcceleration-x-IQR <= 0.073\ngini = 0.834\nsamples = 2881\nvalue = [471, 443, 476, 484, 9, 486, 512, 0]\nclass = Walking"] ;
0 -> 1 [labeldistance=2.5, labelangle=45, headlabel="True"] ;
2 [label="rotationRate-z-IQR <= 0.396\ngini = 0.606\nsamples = 1020\nvalue = [466, 80, 43, 2, 0, 429, 0, 0]\nclass = Push-ups"] ;
1 -> 2 ;
```

This is what I don't understand:

1. If user-acceleration-magnitude-mean is less or equal than 0.973, then the class is "Walking", otherwise I jump to the node 1, right? or it's the other way around?
2. How do I read a label which starts with "gini = 0.596"? gini is not a feature of my decision tree, what does it mean?
3. What about the other values such as nsamples and nvalue? what do they represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: If user-acceleration-magnitude-mean is less or equal than 0.973, follow True. (This is continued downwards into the tree.)

2: I googled a bit, and found the "gini coefficient: a statistical measure of the degree of variation represented in a set of values, used especially in analysing income inequality". I think it has been taken out of the economic context, but I don't know for sure if this is the case.

3: 
There is a underlying structure in this. `samples` is the amount of samples that apply for that node. There are 3878 samples for the root, 2881 for the left child and 997 for the right child. Since 2881 + 997 = 3878 I believe that for 2881 samples `user-acceleration-magnitude-mean <= 0.973` was True. And respectively False for the other 997 samples.

The values also have some sort of underlying structure going on. The sum of every value in the `value` list equals to the amount of `samples` in that node.

Comment: What do you mean by follow True?

Comment: Well, if for a sample `user-acceleration-magnitude-mean <= 0.973` "== True", it belongs to the leftchild. If for a sample `user-acceleration-magnitude-mean <= 0.973` "== False", it belongs to the rightchild.

Comment: It's still not clear. There is no indication of which is the left/right child, and the node 0 has only one child.

Comment: Well i made a .png of the whole code input and each node had 2 childs except for the leafs. The left and right child are simply how i see them on the .png. And the left child is always for "True"